# Mysql : how to update table structure from another database table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 2 DBs  containing table : table1

**DB1 : table1:**
field1
field2
field3
field4
..
field99

**DB2 : table2:**
field1
field2
field3

(so 96 new fields to be added manually !)

I keep on adding new fields to table1 on DB1
ex: DB1.table1 has now 99 fields and DB2.table2 has 3 fields

Is there a way to update DB2.table "quickly" without removing data or dropping the table, so the 96 new fields are added ?
(a kind of structure sync without losing data)

I am doing it manually adding field after field with is a waste of time.

Comment: There is no inbuilt way to synch DDLs you either do it manually or code it - possibly based on infomation_schema.columns.

Comment: *Is there a way to update DB2.table "quickly" without removing data or dropping the table* - what is "quickly"? less handwork or less table locking time?

Comment: quickly = not spending 1 hour on typing the new fields to be added

Comment: *I am doing it manually adding field after field with is a waste of time.* ALTER TABLE allows to add more than one (even all) field in the same statement.

Comment: 'quickly = not spending 1 hour on typing the new fields to be added ' - why would you, you could show create table <tablename> then copy and paste the result into an alter statement - job done

Answer (score -1):

Example.

There are two tables mentioned in the question.

We execute:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table1;
SHOW CREATE TABLE table2;
```

and receive

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `field1` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `field2` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field3` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `field4` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  -- .....
  `field99` int DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `field1` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `field2` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field3` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

We remove all lines except the lines which describes the columns in table1 which are absent in table2 in any text editor obtaining

```
  `field4` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  -- .....
  `field99` int DEFAULT NULL
```

Then we add ALTER TABLE line to the beginning , ADD COLUMN to the beginning of each line and specify INSTANT operation.

```
ALTER TABLE table2
ADD COLUMN
  `field4` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  -- .....
ADD COLUMN
  `field99` int DEFAULT NULL
, ALGORITHM=INSTANT;
```

That's all. May execute.

[sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=610368cfbc7cc3abff0d2fcdedbd4e90)

Answer (score -1):

If you have two tables (for this example only 5 fields):

```
create table table1 (field1 integer, field2 integer, field3 integer, field4 integer, field5 varchar(20));

create table table2 (field1 integer, field2 integer, field3 integer);
```

Then you can see the 'missing' columns using this SQL:

```
select c1.column_name, c2.column_name
from information_schema.columns  c1
left join information_schema.columns  c2 on c2.table_schema=c1.table_schema and c2.table_name='table2' and c2.column_name=c1.column_name
where c1.table_schema='test' and c1.table_name = 'table1' ;

+-------------+-------------+
| COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_NAME |
+-------------+-------------+
| field1      | field1      |
| field2      | field2      |
| field3      | field3      |
| field4      | NULL        |
| field5      | NULL        |
+-------------+-------------+
```

If a stored procedure is created like this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE AddFields (IN Table1 VARCHAR(200), IN Table2 VARCHAR(200))
    BEGIN
        select 
           CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",Table2," ADD COLUMN ",c1.COLUMN_NAME," ",c1.column_type) as AlterStatement
        from information_schema.columns  c1
        left join information_schema.columns  c2 on 
            c2.table_schema=c1.table_schema and 
            c2.table_name=Table2 and c2.column_name=c1.column_name
        where 
            c1.table_schema='test' and 
            c1.table_name = Table1 and
            c2.column_name is null;
    END//
       
DELIMITER ;
```

one can do:

```
mysql> call Addfields('Table1','Table2');
+--------------------------------------------------+
| AlterStatement                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD COLUMN field4 int         |
| ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD COLUMN field5 varchar(20) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Which gives the `ALTER TABLE` statements to do the change.

Some changes might be needed to als take into account the default value(s), but ....

Additional info:

- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html)
- [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)